# Ubuntu 17.10 installation from a thumb drive

Tags: usb

I have tried installing Ubuntu 17.10 several times now, but the process keeps failing.

The installation seems to be going smoothly; however, once the installation is complete, the system asks to be restarted. For some reason, it is this -- the restarting -- part where errors appear.

The error I get is:

> squashfs error unable to read page

It is the first time I am installing Linux and I have no clue what to do, so any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: The install failed. Install it again.

Comment: Sounds like it could be a corrupt ISO download, check the MD5SUM, for Windows see http://www.winmd5.com/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the problem is but with the DVD you have to **leave it in the computer** after the reboot, until it tells you to remove it.

This maybe the same when installing via a flash drive.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, during my first attempt, I, actually, left the usb in until got the message that it was no longer needed, but then I got an error when was restarting the computer: [ 9934.778997] systemd-journald[955]: failed to send WATCHDOG=1 notification message: Transport endpoint is not connected. I didn't find a solution to that error, so, in my following attempts, I ejected the usb right before pressing the restart now button, but got the error message (see the question). That's why I am bit lost now.